# Hensels Lemma in many variables

Tags: field-theory, valuation-theory

Let $(K,v)$ be a henselian valued field, with valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$ and residue field $Kv$.

Then given a polynomial $f \in \mathcal{O}[x]$, henselianity tells that given some suitable non-degeneracy condition, you can lift a zero of $\overline{f}$ in $Kv$ to a zero of $f$ in $\mathcal{O}$. Here $\overline{f}$ denotes the reduction of $f$ modulo the maximal ideal.

I know there are generalizations of this which look at $n$ functions in $n$ variables, and the non-degeneracy condition comes from the Jacobian determinant. I'm interested in a slightly different extension:

$\bf{Question}$: Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial in two (or more) variables over $\mathcal{O}$. Can one specify some non-degeneracy condition which guarantees that solutions from the residue field lift?

Comment: You can look at it as a polynomial in one variable with coefficients that are polynomials in the other variable(s). So if by fixing all but one of the variables you're left with a single-variable polynomial fitting the non-degeneracy condition in one variable, then you get a solution by refining the left over variable and not changing the choices you used for the other variables, e.g., $f(x,y) = x^2 - 5y^2 - 3$ has $f(x,1) = x^2 - 8$ has a simple root $1 \bmod 7$, so there is a 7-adic solution to $f(x,y) = 0$ where $x \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ and $y = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I can see this would be useful in many cases in practice. But I mainly have in mind cases like $f(x,y)=x^p-ay^p-b$ where the residue field has characteristic $p$. Substituting a value for $y$ gives me $x^p-c$ which is a degenerate case so I can't lift. Is it possible there is a more general condition which can make headway in this context?

Comment: It's false that solutions to $x^p - c \bmod p$ can't be lifted. Maybe they can, and maybe they can't. Knowing things mod $p$ is not sufficient, but knowing about solutions mod $p^2$ or $p^3$ may be enough. The *simplest* version of Hensel's lemma concerns lifting nonsingular points mod $p$ into the $p$-adics, but there is a more general version that works modulo powers of $p$ above the first power. Have you seen the classification of squares in the 2-adic integers using Hensel's lemma? That can't use the simplest Hensel lemma.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I spoke a little too fast. However, while I am interested in the residue field having char. $p$, I don't want to assume it's $\mathbb{F}_p$ (or another finite field). It's not immediately clear that the proof from e.g. Course in Arithmetic of the more general Hensels Lemma will generalize to the arbitrary henselian case, since completeness seems to be used in an essential way in Serre. But perhaps the statement is none the less true, replacing "mod $p^n$" with "mod $M^n$" with $M$ the maximal ideal?

Comment: The residue field doesn't have to be finite. There are lots of books that discuss $p$-adic fields, and some of them will discuss a more general form of Hensel's lemma. Lang's Algebraic Number Theory has a flexible one-variable form of Hensel's lemma with initial hypothesis $|f(a)| < |f'(a)|^2$. When that holds, the recursion from Hensel's lemma still works and converges to a root of $f(x)$.

Comment: Here is the same question (with an answer) on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108687/multivariate-hensels-lemma-but-with-only-one-polynomial